# pdf2txt.pyをコマンドプロンプトで実行しても何もおこりません。

Tags: python

書籍の通りにコマンドをうっているのになにもおこりません。これはなぜでしょうか？インターネットの情報を見ても、同じようなトラブルがみつけられません。python3.6 anaconda
windows10を使用しています。なにか見落としがあるのでしょうか？

モジュールはpdfminer3kです。

```
 pdf2txt.py -o output.txt 22.pdf
```

実行するとこのようなものが表示されます。

```
usage: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pdf2txt.py [-d] [-p pagenos] [-m maxpages] [-P password] [-o output] [-C] [-n] [-A] [-V] [-M char_margin] [-L line_margin] [-W word_margin] [-F boxes_flow] [-Y layout_mode] [-O output_dir] [-t text|html|xml|tag] [-c codec] [-s scale] file ...
```

#### 解決方法

BLUEPIXY 氏の指摘通りコマンドに「python」をつけることで解決しました。

Comment: 例えば、`python pdf2txt.py -o output.txt 22.pdf` としてみたらどうなりますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。BLUEPIXY 5 氏の指摘通りコマンドにpythonを付け加えると成功しました。また私の場合ですと、「pdf2txt.py」はanacondaのscriptフォルダにあり、カレントディレクトリに移さないと成功しませんでした。

Comment: スクリプト自体は起動しているが、コマンドライン引数が正しく渡されていない状況だと思われます。スクリプト単体(`python `を付けない)で起動する場合の引数の展開設定については、私はwindows10を使用していないので実際に試してみることができませんが、おそらく類似の例が検索すれば見つかるものと思います。

Comment: Yosh さんのコメントの[リンク先](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40066/pdf2txt-py%e3%82%92%e3%82%b3%e3%83%9e%e3%83%b3%e3%83%89%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%83%b3%e3%83%97%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%82%82%e4%bd%95%e3%82%82%e3%81%8a%e3%81%93%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93/40085?noredirect=1#comment40676_40085)が同じ問題だと思われます。

Answer (score 1):

python に限らずwindowsでは、スクリプトを実行するような場合には、拡張子の関連付けとかその場合の引数の展開方法などの設定が必要になります。
（実行可能拡張子とするにはその設定も必要となります）
質問の状況の場合その(引数の展開の)設定が間違っているか不完全だと思われます。

私はwindows10を使用していないのでwindows10でのそのような方法について詳細を教えることはできませんが
こうした永続的にコマンドとして使用が見込まれるような場合で拡張子`.py`での実行にこだわるのではない場合にはバッチを使用するのがいいかもしれません。

以下その例（適当に自分の環境用に置き換えて下さい）：
まず適当な場所に自分用のコマンドフォルダを用意します。
例：
`c:\my_command`
そしてこのフォルダにパスを通しておきます。
当該スクリプトをこのフォルダにコピーするかバッチでフルパスを指定するようにします。
同じフォルダにバッチファイルを作成します。
例：
バッチファイル名：
`pdf2txt.bat`

内容(フルパスでスクリプトファイルを指定する場合の例（パスに空白が含まれる場合`""`で囲みます。））：

```
python C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pdf2txt.py %*
```

実行例：

```
pdf2txt -o output.txt 22.pdf
```

(`my_command`フォルダ(または実行パス)に同名の`.exe`または`.com`ファイルが無い場合`pdf2txt.bat`の`.bat`は省略できます）

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。batファイルでのコマンド実行の件は「退屈なことをpyhton」にやらせようという書籍に書いてあったので一応わかります。しかし私はpythonをかじった程度の人間で「引数の展開方法の設定」と聞いても何のことだかわからないです。ですが調べる気はあります。今回の貴重な回答大変ありがとうございました。

Comment: @matomebutai  「引数の展‌​開方法の設定」 とはざっくり言うとスクリプトを起動する時の引数として渡す引数の指定のことです。例えば引数を一つ渡すという設定になっていると`pdf2txt.py -o` のように起動することになって"スクリプトの使い方が違うよ"と怒られます。 この場合全ての引数を渡す必要があるワケです。バッチの例で言うと`%*`がそれに当たります。（これは全ての引数に展開されます）

Comment: 例えば引数を一つ渡すという設定になっている‌​と`python pdf2txt.py`かもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。おそらくモジュール側の話ですね。今後このような場面に遭遇したとき同じように対処できるか不安ですが、頭のかたすみにおいておこうと思います。

Comment: モジュール側の話ではありません。あくまでwindowsでの設定の話です。

Comment: related? [stackoverflow:Executable Python Script not take sys.argv in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540541/executable-python-script-not-take-sys-argv-in-windows)

Comment: 的を完全にえています。私はpythonを2つインストールしています。ひとつはVisualStudioからインストールしたpython。もうひとつはanacondaです。

Answer (score 0):

どちらかのオプションの指定が正しくないので、使い方の表示が出てくるのでしょう。

出力をファイル指定ではなく、標準出力のままにしてみるとか、
PDFファイルをフルパス指定にしてみるとか、
カレントフォルダを"C:\Work"等の、
途中のフォルダ名に日本語や空白を含まない場所にして実行するとか、
試してみてください。

こうしたページが参考になりそうです。
英単語帳作成～その1～
http://kuroyagi.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/10/04/201409
pdf2txt.py not executing command
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574629/pdf2txt-py-not-executing-command

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。BLUEPIXY 5 氏指摘の方法で成功しました。kunif氏指摘の方法ですと、pdfファイルのフルパスは試しましたが、成功しませんでした。「カレントフォルダまで日本語含まない」というのはまだ試していません。

Comment: 先ほど、日本語を含まないパスをカレントにして、同じようにやってみましたが成功しませんでした。どうやらパラメータ―？としてpythonはやはり必要なようです。

Comment: 紹介した「英単語帳作成～その1～」に書かれていたのと同様の使い方ですね。参考にされている書籍と違うということは、お使いの環境がその書籍の前提とする状態と違っているからと考えられます。その書籍の中に使用する環境設定に関する説明があれば、それとの違いを調べておいた方が、今後の引っ掛かりを少なくするのに役立つと思われます。

Comment: おっしゃる指摘のとおりかもしれません。書籍の前がきにはwindowsを使用しているという前書きはありませんでした。この話は私にとっては不可解です。通常pyファイルは.pyと指定すれば普通に実行してくれます。pythonと書かないといけないというのが「引数の展開方法」ということなのだという認識をしておこうと思います。